# How to disable requiretty on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sudo, tty, pty

I"m using packer to create automated linux golden images.

When I try and run a script that requires sudo, I get the following error

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

This error has been discussed at length on the internet, the recommended advice is use one of the following:

1. ssh using `-t`
2. Remove from /etc/sudoers `Defaults:username !requiretty`
3. export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass
4. Add user to suoders group `%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

I've verified that the /etc/sudoers file that ships with ubuntu 16.04 does not contain `requiretty`. Why does ubuntu still give error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

[image]

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1482

https://askubuntu.com/questions/281742/sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified

Comment: where's the sudoers config that allows your user to run that script without a password? (in /etc/sudoers.d perhaps?)

Comment: also: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Jeff Schaller I know screenshots are bad. I'm running inside a vm without guest tools so copy and paste isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a problem with the order of scripts.

Once I allowed the vagrant user sudo rights inside the sudoers file, the problem went away.

https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/scripts/ubuntu/sudoers.sh

```
sed -i -e '/Defaults\s\+env_reset/a Defaults\texempt_group=sudo' /etc/sudoers
sed -i -e 's/%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL/%sudo  ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL/g' /etc/sudoers
```